# Can't locate installed software in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, perl

I successfully installed Padre (Perl editor) from software center. But can't locate the installed app. Tried searching but couldn't find. Please help. Screen shot is attached

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkwJB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Padre` itself is located in `/usr/bin/padre` however the `*.desktop` file is in `/usr/share/perl5/auto/share/dist/Padre/padre.desktop` . You can run the `padre` command in terminal  and pin the editor to the launcher once it comes up

Comment: Please upvote if you find this answer useful. If it solves your question, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the grey checkmark to the left of the answer, bellow the up/down arrows

Comment: Thanks Serg. I am able to launch the Padre editor now but don't know how to pin it to the launcher.

Comment: @Santhosh Once it comes up, you should see the icon appear on the launcher. Right click on it. There will be option "Lock to Launcher"